# What are any real sets of rules compilers use to decide whether to inline a function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, compiler-construction, inline

We have a macro for signalling errors in a common utilities library that goes like this:

```
#define OurMacro( condition ) \
    if( condition ) { \
    } else { \
        CallExternalFunctionThatWillThrowAnException( parametersListHere ); \
    } \
```

What I refer to as `parametersListHere` is a comma-separated list of constants and macros that is populated by the compiler at each macro expansion.

That function call always resolves into a call - the function implementation is not exposed to the compiler. The function has six parameters and in debug configuration all of them have meaningful values, while in release configuration only two have meaningful values and others are passed the same default values.

Normally the condition will hold true, so I don't care how fast the invokation is, I only care about the code bloat. Calling that function with 6 parameters requires seven x86 instruction (6 `push`es and one `call`), and clearly 4 of those `push`es can be avoided if the function signature is changed to have two parameters only - this can be done by introducing an intermediate "gate" function implemented in such way its implementation is not visible to the compiler.

I need to estimate whether I should insist on that change. So far the primary improvement I expect is that reducing the number of parameters will drop 4 instructions on each invokation which means that the code surrounding the macro expansion will become smaller and the compiler will inline it more likely and optimize the emitted code further.

How can I estimate that without actually trying and recompiling all our code and carefully analyzing the emitted code? Every time I read about `inline` there's a statement that the compiler decides whether to inline the function.

Can I see some exact set of rules of how the function internals influence compiler decision on inlining?

Comment: Any reason you don't have 2 different functions with a `#ifdef NDEBUG` switch ?

Comment: @Matthieu M.: The original function might be already called from some code I don't know about. Anyway with a new function or by changing the existing function signature I achieve exactly the same result, so it doesn't really matter which way I choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has a fairly large set of options that expose how their process works, documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fno_002dinline-689). It's of course not exact, given that it will be tweaked over time and it's CPU-dependent.

The first rule is "their body is smaller than expected function call code". 
A second rule is "static functions called once".

There are also parameters affecting the inling process, e.g. `max-inline-insns-single`. An `insn` is a pseudo-instruction in the GCC compiler, and is used here as a measure of function complexity. The documentation of parameter `max-inline-insns-auto` makes it clear that manually declaring a function `inline` might cause it to be considered for inlining even if it is too big for automatic inlining.

Inlining isn't a all-or-nothing process, since there's a `-fpartial-inlining` flag.

Of course, you can't consider inlining in isolation. Common Subexpression Elimination (CSE) makes code simpler. It's an optimization pass that may make a function small enough to be inlined. After inlining, new common subexpressions may be discovered so the CSE pass should be run again, which in turn might trigger further inlining. And CSE isn't the only optimization that needs rerunning.

Answer (score 1):

The rules on what functions get inlined and under what conditions (e.g. selected optimization level) are specific to each compiler, so I suggest you check your compiler's documentation. However, a function that just forwards to another function (as you propose) should be a good candidate for inlining by any compiler that supports it.

Some compilers have a mechanism whereby you can flag that you really want a function to be inlined, e.g. MSVC++ has __forceinline.

Comment: I don't propose the forwarding function as a candidate for inlining. I want it to be consealed so that it is never inlined and the code calling it becomes smaller itself.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted the gate function to do. I thought its purpose was to forward the 6-parameter call to a 2-parameter function in release mode, thereby achieving the result you are looking for (i.e. eliminating the code for the extra 4 parameters in a release build, provided that the gate function gets inlined).

Comment: If the gate gets inlined those extra parameters passing gets inlined too and the extra code is back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual C++, you can use [__forceinline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28VS.71%29.aspx) to *force* the compiler to inline a function.